# Array with integers and nil values in golang?

Tags: arrays, go, null, integer

I am new to golang. But I couldn't find an answer to this.

In python I can do,

```
array = [1, 2, 3, None, 5]
```

But in go when I write

```
var array = [5]int {1, 2, 3, nil, 5}
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

```
cannot convert nil to type int
```

How can I create an array in golang which is a mix of integer and nil values?

Comment: Nil isn't an integer. A "nil" int is just 0.

Comment: I want to create an array which serves as an input to a function. 0 will also be a valid input. When I want the function to ignore some values in the input sequence, I want something equivalent of None in Python.

Comment: Non you cannot do this, no matter how hard you try. You _must_ use a different type, e.g. a *int.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First a bit of theory. Python is a dynamically typed language. While each individual value has a type, your variables can be assigned values of any type without a problem. As a consequence, python collections can contain multiple types of values and don't complain. The following is a valid python tuple `(1, 'a', None, True)`. Go is a statically typed language. If your variable is defined as an integer you cannot assign any non-integer value to it. As a consequence, collections in Go have a type and can only contain a single type of object.

Now to practice. There are a few ways to do what you want. The classical C way would be to pick an integer value you are never going to encounter and use that as a null value. A 0 or a -1 or something. This is not very robust though.

A more idiomatic way is to define your own type.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type NilInt struct {
    value int
    null  bool
}

func (n *NilInt) Value() interface{} {
    if n.null {
        return nil
    }
    return n.value
}

func NewInt(x int) NilInt {
    return NilInt{x, false}
}

func NewNil() NilInt {
    return NilInt{0, true}
}

func main() {
    var x = []NilInt{NewNil(), NewInt(10), NewNil(), NewInt(5)}
    for _, i := range x {
        fmt.Printf("%v ", i.Value())
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: I like having a new type for the int but think it would be simpler to just make it a new int type with a value function on it.  If the slice is a pointer to this type then you can put `nil` directly in the slice without the need for a NilInt function of the extra boolean.  You can then also do an equality test for `== nil` rather than having to call value. See this working example: https://play.golang.org/p/YsKfjpBU6jo

Comment: I tried doing that, but it doesn't seem to work for me in Go 1.11. Not sure if I did something wrong, but it wouldn't allow assigning nil even to a custom int type.

Answer (score 4):

Every type in go has a "zero value" which it is assigned when it is created to make sure it is always initialized.  For int the "zero value" is 0, for strings "".  There are some things that can have `nil` as their value though:

- pointers
- interfaces
- maps
- slices
- channels
- function types

Only the first is really relevant here though.  If you want an int that is nil you have to declare it as a pointer to that int.  As slices can't have mixed types you then need to make the slice a slice of type pointer to int: `*int`.  So you could have a slice of pointers to ints that included a nil value:

```
zero := 0
ints := []*int{&zero, nil}
for _, anInt := range ints {
    if anInt != nil {
        fmt.Println(*anInt)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(anInt)
    }
}
```

The `*anInt` in the println dereferences the pointer turning it into an `int` rather than a pointer to an `int`.

https://play.golang.org/